# How to check the weight of product in cart based on meta_key?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for a solution to check the weight in the cart based on meta.
for example, it prints: :

- 5kg in your basket is Cold and Hot
- 2.5kg in your basket is other

I use the following loop to check the meta_key:

```
$category_check = false;
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    $product = $cart_item['data'];
    if ( $cold = $product->get_meta('cold_product') or $hot= $product->get_meta( 'hot_product' ) ) {
    $category_check = true;
    break;
    }
}
```

Then after checking products with a special meta, I want to calculate the weight.

```
 if (category_check ) {
        echo 'your basket include:';

     // I stock in this stage 
     // Show total weight of product $cold and $hot
    
}
```

Would you please give me some tips regarding create the second loop?
In fact, I need a new variation like `$new_weight` to hold the total weight of products that is both `$cold` and `$hot`.

Comment: **1)** _"I use the following loop to check the category:"_  The code you posted does not check for category. **2)** Where do you want that message to appear? where specific?
what page? above, below, behind, in front... Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & then write your question with details to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks @7uc1f3r, I am really surprised, while I asked my question in detail, someone come and say: StackOverflow is not for doing your personal project. While I just ask for part of m problem, you say it is not in detail.  I just looking for a solution to complete the second loop. To calculate the total weight of the products which are in both $cold and $hot.

Comment: Where in my comment do i indicate _"StackOverflow is not for doing your personal project."_ I only ask to clarify your question so that an appropriate answer can be given versus just some advice. The advice might be understandable to you personally, but not to some other users on SO. Although the intention is to write the answers on SO in such a way that they are understandable for everyone and not just for the questioner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer and I put it here to share with others:

```
$cat_check = false;
$w= 0;
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    $product = $cart_item['data'];
    $weight=$product->get_weight() * $cart_item['quantity'];
       if ( $cold = $product->get_meta('cold_product') or $coldsummer = $product->get_meta( 'cold_product_summer' ) ) {
       $cat_check = true;
       $w = $w + $weight;
       }                
}
```

Then I use the following part to print it:

```
if ($cat_check) {
   echo '<p>your basket include: ' . $w . ' kg special products.</p>';
}
```